# How Do I Search Data From Two Tables using Join

Tags: php

This is My SELECT Query For searching user from the DB.  The problem is I am only able to get the search result of those users who have posted any content in their `postImg` table.  Otherwise there is no user found. I want to search in such a way that even if any user has not posted any post then it should be found. I am using this query:

```
 <?php 
        $sql =  "SELECT * FROM postImg LEFT JOIN user ON postImg.userID=user.userID 
        WHERE user.userID='".$page_owner."' AND (userName LIKE '%".$searchVal."%') GROUP BY user.userID ";
        $res3 = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
        while($row2=mysql_fetch_assoc($res3)){
        echo $row2['userName']; // From user Table

        echo $row2['likes'];    // From postImg table
        echo $row2['posts'];    // From postImg table
       } ?>
```

Comment: So you want to return all users, even if they do not have a corresponding row in `postImg`? Have you tried changing `... FROM postImg LEFT JOIN user ...` to `... FROM user LEFT JOIN postImg  ...`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$sql =  "SELECT * FROM postImg RIGHT JOIN user ON postImg.userID=user.userID 
    WHERE user.userID='".$page_owner."' AND (userName LIKE '%".$searchVal."%') GROUP BY user.userID ";
```

Comment: What happens when you run it?

Comment: Sorry And Yeah It Worked For Me Thank You Very Much That was so simple But I Dont know y i didnt think of that i tried inner left outer but forgot to try Right thank u very much

Answer (score 0):

I think that you want `user LEFT JOIN postImg`, not the other way around as you have it here.

The query as-written will return every record from `postImg` whether-or-not it has an associated `user`.

Obviously, you want every `user` whether or not s/he has a `postImg`.

Incidentally, I think that changing it to `RIGHT JOIN` would work also, as Robert suggested in *his* answer.  But, I can count on the fingers of one hand the number of times that I've seen a `RIGHT` join . . . hence, I suggested flipping the table-names. *("Give 'em what they're used to.")*

---

**Edit:**   To clarify (for the benefit of the Peanut Gallery ...):   these two forms of so-called "outer joins" *are* equivalent.  The terms, `LEFT` and `RIGHT`, simply refer to which one of the two tables is the master ... "the one on the `LEFT` side," *before* the word `JOIN`, (`postImg` in the query shown in the original post), or, "the one on the `RIGHT`", *after* the word `JOIN`. (`user`) All of the rows in what I'm calling the "master" will be returned, along with whatever matching values in the "other" table as may be found.

For whatever reason, I very rarely find `RIGHT` joins being used in production code. It's not that they *can't* be done, of course, but simply that I've observed that it *isn't* (usually) done.